# Retrieving specific images from Media Library in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, loops

I developed a theme in which I show a Bootstrap carousel filled with sponsor images.
At the moment the sponsor-images are hardcoded like this:

```
<div class="item active">
  <div class="row outerDiv">
    <div class="col-xs-12 innerDiv">
      <a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/recruiting-messe/"><img class="carImg img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/Sponsoren/PremiumSponsoren.jpg" alt="Premium Sponsoren" style="margin: 0 auto;"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want my authors to be able to change the images without being required to dig into the code itself, but I don't know how to go about it. I thought about maybe retrieving images uploaded into the media library with a certain naming convention or a caption "sponsor" with a loop? 
What would be the best way to implement something like this and how?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
$attachment_meta = wp_get_attachment(your_attachment_id);
$caption = $attachment_meta['caption'];

if($caption == 'sponsor') :
// show me the money
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just use a plug in for it? Or designate a post,attach a gallery, and use gallery short code for a simple bootstrap carousel to use? Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do the following, use some meta fields plugin like  [this](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and add image field where the author can choose which image is sponsored. Then you can do something like this

```
if($current_attachment_id == get_field('image_field')){
     //Do the trick
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help. I solved the problem by querying for attachements with a specific title "SponsorenBanner".

```
$query_images_args = array(
      'post_type'      => 'attachment',
      'post_mime_type' => 'image',
      'post_status'    => 'inherit',
      'posts_per_page' => - 1,
      'title' => 'SponsorenBanner',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      );

    $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

    $images = array();
    foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {

      $images[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );

    }
```